# Single-Diode calculation keeps not converging

Tags: python, modeling, pvlib

I am trying to calculate the power of a PV-Module with the pvlib.singlediode() function. In before I fit the parameters, which I do with the calcparams_pvsyst() function. For calcparams_pvsyst() I use the parameters that I get from reading my module into Pvsyst (the Desktop Programm). 
My problem is, that my singlediode funtion is not converging. I get the error: Exception: EXCEPTION:iterations exceeded maximum (50). 
 Is there a possiblity to fix this. I already tried different methods in the singlediode-function. Is it maybe possible, that I exported my parameters from pvsyst to calcparams_pvsyst() wrong.
What is important to notice is, that for most of the input data the model is working, but only for some input data it is not converging. This data has no suspicious Irradiance or temperature values.

```
total_irr = row["Irradiation"]
temp_cell = sapm_cell_from_module(row["Temp"], total_irr, deltaT)
IL, I0, Rs, Rsh, nNsVth = calcparams_pvsyst(total_irr, temp_cell, 0.004491, 0.95, -0.072, 9.98, 1.4e-11, R_sh_ref=300, R_sh_0=1200, R_s=0.252, cells_in_series=60, R_sh_exp=5.5, EgRef=1.121, irrad_ref=1000, temp_ref=25)
single_diode_res = singlediode(IL, I0, Rs, Rsh, nNsVth )
```

Does any of the parameters in calcparams_pvsyst() seem completely unrealistic?

Comment: Double-check the units (e.g. that `alpha_sc` value might not be in A/degC).  If all of those check out, can you please include some irradiance and temperature values that reproduce the exception?

Comment: I used a wrong value for mu_gamma. When using the correct value which can be found in PVSYST for the module I use, the result ist converging. For my module it was -0.001 instead of -0.072 for mu_gamma which is a totally different value.